# Why does only one column appear in my PHP search results output?

Tags: php

I have a search.php page that successfully searches a database called "sixcols" and displays the correct number of results.  But suddenly, it only displays information from the first column of each result. No matter which of the six types of columns I list first in the code, only that column appears. I have no idea why all 6 aren't appearing.

I know mysql_fetch_array is becoming depracated, but I swear this worked this morning and I don't know what I changed.

I've searched for 2 hours for a typo or an explanation and I can't figure it out. Any help is much appreciated!

Here's the code:

```
<?php

error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');

$search_output = "";
if(isset($_POST['searchquery']) && $_POST['searchquery'] != ""){
$searchquery = preg_replace('#[^a-z 0-9?!]#i', '', $_POST['searchquery']);
$sqlCommand = "SELECT Subcategory, Type, Author, Summary, Date, Source FROM sixcols WHERE Author LIKE '%$searchquery%' OR Summary LIKE '%$searchquery%'";

        include_once("connect.php");

$query = mysql_query($sqlCommand) or die(mysql_error());

$count = mysql_num_rows($query);
if($count > 1){
$search_output .= "<hr />$count results for <strong>$searchquery</strong><hr />";
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)){

            $Subcategory = $row["Subcategory"];
            $Type = $row["Type"];
            $Author = $row["Author"];
            $Summary = $row["Summary"];
            $Date = $row["Date"];
            $Source = $row["Source"];
   $search_output .= '<br/> <span class="subcategory">' . $Subcategory . '</span>'; '<span class="type">' . $Type . '</span>'; '<span class="author">' . $Author . '</span>'; '<span class="summary">' . $Summary . '</span>'; '<br/> <span class="date">' . $Date . '</span>'; '<span class="source">' . $Source . '</span>';
                } // close while
} else {
$search_output = "<hr />0 results for <strong>$searchquery</strong><hr />$sqlCommand";
}
}
?>
```

Comment: Get rid of the `'; '` between each `span` if you want to keep it on one line. You're only seeing $subcategory because of the ; after the first closing span.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a syntax issue where you stop appending to `$search_output`. You should turn error reporting on to catch these errors.

```
$search_output .= '<br/> <span class="subcategory">' . $Subcategory . '</span>'; 
$search_output .= '<span class="type">' . $Type . '</span>';
$search_output .= '<span class="author">' . $Author . '</span>';
$search_output .= '<span class="summary">' . $Summary . '</span>';
$search_output .= '<br/> <span class="date">' . $Date . '</span>';
$search_output .= '<span class="source">' . $Source . '</span>';
```

You also need to stop using `mysql_` functions. They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which.

Answer (score 0):

You get one column because of this:

```
$search_output .= '<br/> <span class="subcategory">' . $Subcategory . '</span>';
```

Anything after the semicolon is not appended to the `$search_output` string.

Answer (score 0):

```
$search_output .= '<br/> <span class="subcategory">' . $Subcategory . '</span> <span class="type">' . $Type . '</span> <span class="author">' . $Author . '</span> <span class="summary">' . $Summary . '</span> <br/> <span class="date">' . $Date . '</span>  <span class="source">' . $Source . '</span>';
```